# Protect SQL Server Express data file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transparent-data-encryption

I need to protect a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 data file (`.mdf`) against restoring/attaching on another machine. I'm aware of TDE or Transparent Data Encryption but unfortunately this option is not available in Express version. Any other way to protect the database?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're asking because you want to secure your database from local administrators? This question might be relevant: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34684/restrict-access-for-windows-administrator

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do encryption with express edition but can you can do it by other way

or file encryption only. For more reference follow http://sqlmag.com/database-security/sql-server-encryption-options.

Comment: I'm sorry but the link seems to be broken - could you recall what was it's content?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is ok to mention our third party product here, [NetLib Encryptionizer](https://netlibsecurity.com/products/sql-server-encryption/).  It provides Transparent Data Encryption for all versions and editions of SQL Server including SQL Express.

I am the Founder and CTO of NetLib Security Inc.

Comment: Totally fine as long as you disclose your affiliation, Neil. Can you provide some more details about the product, though? Cost, performance stats, or something? Link only answers are generally less helpful than ones that contain at least some of the content of the site linked to.